# How should you handle the retry of sending a JMS message from your application to ActiveMQ if the ActiveMQ server is down?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

So using JMS and ActiveMQ, I can be sure that my message sent from my Spring Boot application using JmsTemplate will reach it's destination application even if that destination application is down at the time I send the message to ActiveMQ. As when the destination application starts up, it grabs the message from the queue. Great!

However.

What happens if my Spring Boot application tries to send a JMS message to a queue on the ActiveMQ server, but the ActiveMQ server is down at that point or the network is down and I get a connection refused exception?

What is the recommended way to make sure my application keeps trying to re-sends the message to ActiveMQ until it is successful?  Is this something I have to develop into my application myself?  Are there any nifty Spring tools or annotations which do this for me?  Any advice on best practice or how I should be handling this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Spring-Retry. Has lots of fine grain controls for it:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry

If it is critical that you don't lose this message, you will want to save it to some alternative persistent store (e.g. filesystem, local mq server) along with whatever retry code you come up with. But for those occasional network glitches or a very temporary mq shutdown/restart, Spring-Retry alone should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  Although the other answers are also helpful, yours specifically caters for my concern that my application server CANNOT connect due to network issues.  Only having a failover ActiveMQ server wont help that scenario, however, your suggestion does give me some direction.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of approaches I can think of
   1. You can set up another ActiveMq as fallback. In your code you don't have to do anything, just change your broker url from

```
 activemq.broker.url=tcp://amq01.blah.blah.com:61616
```

to

```
activemq.broker.url=failover:(tcp://amq01.blah.blah.com:61616,tcp://amq02.blah.blah.com:61616)?randomize=false
```

The rest is automatically taken care of. i.e. when one of them is down, the  messages are sent to other.

2. Another approach is to send to a internal queue (like seda, direct) when activemq is down and read from there.

Answer (score 1):

Adding failover to the url is one appropriate way.

And another reasonable way is to making sure activemq always online , as activemq has the master-slave mode(http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) to get high availability.